# How in Yii2 can I register Plugin without using this plugin? )

Tags: jquery-select2, yii2

I have a little problem! Can anyone explain me how can I register plugin (Select2) on page without using this plugin? I need just .js and .css files included in DOM. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in your view file you need to register Assets for this plugin:

```
<?= \kartik\widgets\Select2Asset::register($this);?>
```